# upgrade minikube at "Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"

Tags: linux, kubernetes, upgrade, minikube

This is my current setup:

```
os1@os1:/usr/local/bin$ minikube update-check

CurrentVersion: v1.20.0

LatestVersion: v1.25.1

os1@os1:/usr/local/bin$ cat /etc/os-release

PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
```

What should be the steps to upgrade the minikube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/) is an executable, in this case you would need to `re-install` the `minikube` with the desired version. There is no command to upgrade the running `Minikube`.

You would need to:

```
sudo minikube delete             # remove your minikube cluster
sudo rm -rf ~/.minikube          # remove minikube
```

and reinstall it using [Minikube documentation - Start](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/), depends on what your requirements are (packaged used in docs should be always up to date and should cover all your requirements regarding available drivers).